# Reading numbers into a data frame: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, dataframe, closures

I have the code below which is trying to calculate the amount of time passed since the occurrence of the first event. I am unable to get the variables to read into the data frame and keep getting the error: Error in traumatimes.df[j, "Relative Time"] <- reltime : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

I understand this means I am probably referring to a function and not a variable, any suggestions as to how to restructure the code to get rid of this issues?

```
    setwd("C:/Users/natbenda/SkyDrive/Documents")
df.all <- read.csv("SP Trauma.csv")

TraumaTimes<-function(df) {

  traumatimes.df<-data.frame
  seqnum <- unique(df.all$num)
  reltime <- 0

for (i in 1:seqnum){

  seq <- seqnum[i] ##names loop variable
  seqdf <- df.all[which(df.all$num == seq),]
  unibehave <- unique(seqdf$DateTime)
  numbehave <-length(unibehave)
  timedf <- seqdf$DateTime
  timeone <- timedf[1]
  firsttime <- strptime(timeone, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")

  for (j in 1: numbehave){

  numb <- unibehave[j] ##names loop variable
  behavedf <- seqdf[which(seqdf$DateTime == numb),]
  timebehave <- strptime(behavedf$DateTime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")
  reltimeno <- difftime(timebehave,firsttime, units = "mins")
  reltime <-as.numeric(reltimeno)
  Stage <- as.character(behavedf$stage)
  category <- as.character(behavedf$Category)
  element <- as.character(behavedf$Element)
  who <- as.character(behavedf$who)
  ID <- as.character(behavedf$ID)

  traumatimes.df[j,"num"] <- seq
  traumatimes.df[j,"ID"] <- ID
  traumatimes.df[j,"Relative Time"] <- reltime
  traumatimes.df[j,"Stage"] <- Stage
  traumatimes.df[j,"Category"] <- category
  traumatimes.df[j,"element"] <- element
  traumatimes.df[j,"Who"] <- who

  }
return(traumatimes.df)
}
}
write.csv(TraumaTimes(), file = "SP Trauma Times.csv")
```

Comment: Think about what the line `traumatimes.df<-data.frame` is doing for a moment, and I think you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @joran's comment, you have assigned the function `data.frame` to `traumatimes.df`. You seem to want to have assigned an empty data frame (the result of calling `data.frame`) instead.

```
traumatimes.df <- data.frame()
```